# Phonegap using CLI to compile windows phone app

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

Pardon me for asking, or pointing this out, but the windows mobile docs for phonegap are **awful**.

As of Phonegap 3.0, heres what it still says on the [windows platform guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Platform%20Guide):

`Download and extract the latest copy of [PhoneGap. You will be working in the lib\windows-phone-8\wp8 subfolder, lib\windows-phone-8\wp7 contains the Windwos Phone 7 version of Cordova.`

However, phonegap is no longer distributed as a zip. It is compiled for your specific OS/SDK in the command line.  This doesn't make much sense to me.

`phonegap create Test123` -> `phonegap cd Test123` -> `phonegap build ios` will build your ios platform successfully.  I've done this with no problems.

But I have no idea where they address how to do this for windows mobile.

Have I overlooked where they state this?  Thanks

Comment: 'phonegap platform add wp8'. Then 'phonegap build wp8'